# spring error 404 resource not available

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i am new spring mvc  using spring with java config.i am getting 404 error. my web-default.xml like below

```
 <servlet-mapping> <servlet-name>default</servlet-name> 
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping>
```

and controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/changepwd", method = RequestMethod.GET)

 public String changepwd(ModelMap model) {          
     return "/changepwd.jsp";
 }
```

and my jsp page is

```
 <form name="login-form" class="login-form" action="changepwd">
</form>
```

how to resolve this

Comment: what is your request structure and class structure.

Comment: i am using springtoolsuite with maven

Comment: javaresorces-->src/main/java/LoginContoller

Comment: Deployed Resources-->webapps-->chagepwd.jsp

Comment: remove `/` from return in your controller as `return "changepwd.jsp";`. I hope your view-resolver if configured properly

Comment: i tried but not working

Comment: you have provided less info. please update your question with the log and the url you are trying to access

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /agadmin/changepwd in local

Comment: is there any error in `server.log`

Comment: not showing error in console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101292/discussion-between-mohammad-faisal-and-mohammed-haneef).